# convert all -ve values from a formula calculation into zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am using below formula in all cells, and the result may be a -ve value (below zero).In this project I need to update zero into all such cells. I have tried to put all into a IF statement but it giving me error. How can I do it here

```
=SUMIFS(raw_data!$D:$D,raw_data!$A:$A,$A3,raw_data!$C:$C,C$2)-SUM($B3:INDEX(3:3,COLUMN()-1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:  Change your formula to

```
=MAX(your_formula, 0)
```